# Referencing a picturebox using a variable image in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables, object, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to modify an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887878/referencing-an-object-using-a-variable-string-in-visual-basic-2010) but I'm not having much luck....

What I'm trying to do is:

I have 12 pictures and 12 pictureboxes.
In a loop I'm trying to get it to check for the number and load the corresponding image(s)
so if it's #3 it should load images 1-3 in pictureboxes 1-3

I think I'm close but i can't figure it out

Declaration of Dictionary and passing subroutine

```
Dim ctrlDict As New Dictionary(Of Image, Control)
Dictionary(ctrlDict)
```

Definition Sub

```
 Sub dicti(pictures() As Image, ByRef ctrlDict As Dictionary(Of Image, Control))

    ctrlDict.Add(pictures(0), PictureBox1)
    ctrlDict.Add(pictures(1), PictureBox2)
    ctrlDict.Add(pictures(3), PictureBox3)

End Sub
```

Loop

The error I'm getting  is "programname.my.resources is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression" and "picturebox is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

```
Sub Output(Days() As String, Prices() As String, WhichDay As String, total As Double, ctrlDict As Dictionary(Of Image, Control))

    For i As Integer = 0 To 11
        If WhichDay >= i Then
            ctrlDict(PictureBox & i).Image = pictures(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
Dim pic As PictureBox

    For i As Integer = 0 To 11
        If WhichDay >= i Then
            pic = Me.Controls("picturebox" & i + 1)
            pic.Image = pictures(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, Pretty sure you cant do

```
ctrlDict(PictureBox & i).Image = pictures(i)
```

youll need to find the control that has the name property equal to (PictureBox.name & i). Then use that control and set the image.

Dont have an IDE on this computer but it will be something like

```
dim controlToUse as PictureBox
for each ctrl in ctrlDict
    if ctrl.value.name = "Whatever youre calling your pictureboxes" & i then
        controlToUse = ctrl.value
        exit for
    end if
next

if not controlToUse is nothing then controlToUse.image = pictures(i)
```

Please note that the above is psuedocode. Do not expect it to compile!